# Is there a way to include external Javascript as a source to Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am trying to configure jasmine.yml (using jasmine gem) to use JQuery served from Google API instead of downloading it locally to my server. I.e.:

```
src_files:
  - ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js
```

Unfortunately this does not seem to work, since (as per the comments in the config file) it is looking for filepaths relative to src_dir. Is this not possible then?

Thanks

Ruy

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm guessing it might not be encouraged to include external files into a test environment, since they are pretty much "out of your control". In my case however I'd like to include a file hosted on localhost with a different port — meaning, I do have full control.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up writing the javascript include via spec helper - in my case the Livereload script:

```
document.write('<script src="http://' + (location.host || 'localhost').split(':')[0] + ':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></' + 'script>');
```

It’s a bit hacky but works. You might want to define more accurately where the script is being inserted.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [`jasmine-rails`](https://github.com/searls/jasmine-rails) gem you can create your own `layouts/jasmine_rails/spec_runner.html`, and add the remote dependency there.

```
!!! 5
%html
  %head
    %title Jasmine Specs
    = stylesheet_link_tag *jasmine_css_files
    %script(src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false')
    = javascript_include_tag *jasmine_js_files
  %body
    #jasmine_content
    = yield
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/):

```
$.getScript( external_script_url, function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
  some code to execute after script is loaded
});
```

In case you also want to include jQuery externally, you have to load it this way

```
document.write('<script src="http://.../jquery.min.js</script>')
```