# How to unit test functions in a module?

Tags: javascript, module, jasmine

I'm new to a project where there is a JavaScript script `a3.panel.js` written by someone else. It defines an module like this:

```
a3.panel = (function () {
    let property1 = {},
        property2 = $('.checkbox');

    function someMethods () {
        some logic
    };

    return ({
        some value
    });
})();
```

with Jasmine, how can I test the method inside this module? I tried

```
describe("panel test", () => {
    it("should test", () => {
        var panel = a3.panel;
        expect(typeof a3.panel.property1).toBe("object");
    });
});
```

and Jasmine returns:

```
ReferenceError: a3 is not defined
```

Comment: Did you referenced your file which contains the module? ... `/// <reference path="../Scripts/a3.panel.js" />`

Comment: @SlavaIvanov I included `<script src="http://localhost:53590/Scripts/a3/a3.panel.js"></script>` in Jasmine `SpecRunner.html`.

Comment: Is it loaded? The reason of your module `undefined` is ... it is not loaded (not properly included) or not loaded yet (order/lazy loading, etc.). Use browser dev tools to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the external library is not loaded for the test.

Can you try this in your Jasmine test (I haven't tried yet)- 
`document.write('<script src="http://.../a3library.js></script>')`

You may provide local path too.

OR

Use [jQuery GetScript](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)

And

Check this too - [include external Javascript as a source to Jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8833513/2086966)

Comment: It turns out that something was not properly loaded, I tried again it worked, thanks!